# Spoofing Firefox HTTP headers - not just UserAgent

Tags: firefox, http-headers, firefox-addon, httprequest

I want to modify the list of system fonts, or installed addons and NPAPIs reported. Or even the timezone and computer time, etc

I want an addon that generalizes those headers and others. I don't want them stripped (that's suspicious and even more identifying, and might cause problems with certain sites), I just want them to report generic browser default values like just the original Windows fonts, no plugins (or a very popular one) and so on

TamperData and UserAgent (and the likes) don't allow that deep tampering and are static (if I update FF version, I have to update the string to the new values); plugins, addons & fonts are still reported. Is there a FF addon that allows me to control the headers sent and their data?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the things you are describing aren't headers, they are things that are queried via JS, so you can't alter them using a tools or an API that changes header values.